# Wintersmith: Two paginated sections

Tags: wintersmith

In my wintersmith-built site, I want to have:

- index.html containing a news feed
- blog.html containing a blog index

I copied paginator.coffee into newspaginator.coffee, tweaked it to return 'news' instead of 'articles', and with a couple of other adjustments, it works fine.

Then I tried to add the original paginator back in, with some parameters in config.json:

```
  "plugins": [
    "./plugins/newspaginator.coffee",
    "./plugins/paginator.coffee"
  ],
  "newspaginator": {
    "articles": "news",
    "perPage": 10
  },
  "paginator": {
    "articles": "articles",
    "template": "blog.jade",
    "first": "blog.html",
    "filename": "blogpage/%d/index.html",
    "perPage": 3
  }
```

Now: I only get the HTML page for whichever plugin comes second. As above, I get blog.html but no index.html. If I reverse the order of the two plugins, I get index.html but no blog.html.

How do I get it to do both?

Comment: But, if I use the preview server, it will build index.html *and* blog.html upon request. `wintersmith build` will produce only one of the indices, however (but I need both).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few wintersmith properties that paginator.coffee sets that need to be accounted for in your "tweaks" or one plugin will override the settings of the other.  Here are the ones I've noticed:

```
options = env.config.paginator or {}
...
env.helpers.getArticles = getArticles
...
env.registerGenerator 'paginator', (contents, callback) ->
```

Take env.helpers.getArticles for example. Somewhere in your templates you'll call something like env.helpers.getArticles(contents).  That will be the method for whichever plugin is called second, since the second plugin overrides the value that the first set.

You should be able to get it to work by changing those three lines.  This is still a bit of a hacky solution, since you're duplicating code (DRY Principles) but it could be a good quick fix since it doesn't seem the paginator plugin was set up to work on more than one directory.